# Inequality Implication

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, inequality, normed-spaces

By what definition/theorem can I conclude that $|a-b| <c \rightarrow |a| < |b|+c$ ?

I'm using this in the context of proving limits for an Analysis class. Don't see where this apparently simple implication is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: $\big||a|-|b|\big|\leq |a-b|$. Could you finish?

Comment: Yes. So by the hint:

$||a| - |b|| \leq|a-b|<c$.

Then, $||a| - |b||<c$ $\rightarrow$  $-c<|a| -|b| < c$ 

$\rightarrow$ $|b|-c<|a|<|b|+ c$, which is what I what I was looking for.

Comment: @JKM, Yes, you are right